# How can I get the screen size in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to know if it is possible to calculate the screen size using Tkinter.

I wanted this so that can make the program open up in the center of the screen...

Comment: It depends on the platform you want to acomplish this. So maybe you should let us know on what operating systems this should work...

Comment: you should find an answer in this stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129322/how-do-i-get-monitor-resolution-in-python

Answer (score 108, accepted):

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
```

Comment: This method will fail with multiple screen setups, but there is a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56913005/5218354) to that.

Comment: This actually doesn't handle my current Windows config, running a 50" 4k TV. The above tells me that my monitor is 2560x1440 instead of the actual 3840x2160 with 150% scaling.  So, the Python calls are coming back with the "scaled" resolution.

Comment: @Gary02127 same. The answer below actually helped me out.

Comment: @10 Rep: Which answer? [VoteCoffee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949844/how-to-get-the-screen-size-in-tkinter/66248631#66248631)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen This was a year ago so I don't remember but I believe it is Nandit TIku;s answer.

Answer (score 6):

A possible solution

```
import os

os.system("xrandr  | grep \* | cut -d' ' -f4")
```

My output:

```
1440x900
0
```

Comment: Does this solution depend on X11? How likely is a user to have X11 on a mac?

Comment: @wookie: No obfuscated code, nor regex, just three commands available in any standard GNU/Linux system supporting X and RandR. Simply concatenated one after another by the pipe symbol.

Comment: @Nandit Tiku: Nice and short code. Is it possible to somehow (I am a dummy linux-wise) give the found monitor sizes not as strings but as values to an output tuple or something?

Comment: This outputs the value to the console, but does not pass it to python. Working on stdout piped version...

Comment: A piped version (and other) in a comprehensive list here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129322/how-do-i-get-monitor-resolution-in-python

Comment: Where does this work? What is xrandr? (["xrandr is an official configuration utility to the RandR (Resize and Rotate) X Window System extension"](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/xrandr)). [RandR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.Org_Server#Software_architecture) - *"The X.Org Server implements the server side of the X Window System core protocol version 11 (X11) and extensions to it, e.g. RandR."*.

Comment: Can you elaborate? E.g. for the previous comment and on which system this was tested (Linux?), incl. version. Please respond by [editing (changing) your question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3950195/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 3):

For Windows:

You can make the process aware of [DPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch) to handle scaled displays.

```
import ctypes
try: # Windows 8.1 and later
    ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(2)
except Exception as e:
    pass
try: # Before Windows 8.1
    ctypes.windll.user32.SetProcessDPIAware()
except: # Windows 8 or before
    pass
```

Expanding on [mouad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949844/how-to-get-the-screen-size-in-tkinter/3949983#3949983), this function is capable of handling multi-displays and returns the resolution of the current screen:

```
import tkinter
def get_display_size():
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.update_idletasks()
    root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
    root.state('iconic')
    height = root.winfo_screenheight()
    width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    root.destroy()
    return height, width
```