# How do I get a window's current size using Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

How do I get a windows current size using Tkinter, or possibly with the python standard library?

Comment: duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949844/python-calculate-the-screen-size/3949983#3949983

Comment: @mouad: **No**, not a dup of that.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use the following universal widget methods (where `w` is a widget):

```
w.winfo_height()
w.winfo_width()
```

You can also use the following:

```
w.winfo_reqheight()
w.winfo_reqwidth()
```

Read about [Universal widget methods](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/universal.html).

Comment: be aware that those two can give drastically different results. _height/_width give the actual sizes.

Answer (score 0):

The answers above did not give me the correct result. Here is my solution to get the correct current window size (in pixel).

```
w._current_width
w._current_height
```