# How do i get aspect ratio of system display resolution in python?

Tags: python

How do i get aspect ratio of system display resolution in python?

When I check for display resolution in Ubuntu, I see 1024x768(4:3). How do I get aspect ratio 4:3 in Python?

Comment: What do you mean "check for display resolution"?  Are you using some API to get the resolution now?

Comment: I meant display resolution we find in system display settings. The resolution I see is 1366x768(16:9). I have been able to get the resolution part...But I do not know if its possible to get the aspect ratio using Python.

Answer (score 2):

For this answer I used the following resource: [How to get the screen size in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949844/python-calculate-the-screen-size/3949983#3949983)

The question you're asking is (1) How do I get the screen resolution in Python (2) How do I convert this resolution to a aspect ration. I solved this problem in the following way:

```
import Tkinter
import Fraction as f

root   = Tkinter.Tk()

width  = root.winfo_screenwidth()
height = root.winfo_screenheight()
frac   = f.Fraction(width,height)

print frac
```

Note that this gives the lowest denominator. So for a 1680x1050 screen this is 8/5 instead of a possibly expected 16/10.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Peter. I do not see the use of Fraction here..I just want the ratio specified in the system..for ex..my system has a resolution of 1366x768 with aspect ratio 16:9...How do i get 16:9 in Python.

Comment: 1366x768 does not work like you expected because it is not exactly 16:9. It only approximates 16:9.

Comment: OK...but is it possible to get that ratio in Python.

Comment: If you are only interested in a few aspect ratios and want to include approximate values you could just try to compare the fraction in decimals: 1.33 for 4:3, 1.6 for 16:10, 1.77 for 16:9.
Replace frac = float(width)/float(height) to get the fraction in decimals.

Comment: Could you accept or up-vote my answer if it was useful for you?