# Is it possible to get the scaling percentage of the screen resolution?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, screen-resolution

I am trying to resize my window app according to the resolution.
My computer resolution as we can see in the screenshot is 3840 x 2160 with a 300% scaling.
With this code:

```
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics
import win32con

print("Width =", GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN))
print("Height =", GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN))
```

I get :

```
Width = 1280
Height = 720
```

Because of the scaling

[image: My screen settings]

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66248631/3991125

Comment: Getting the same values

Comment: as i know scaling has nothing to do with resolution

Comment: The problem is that if I use the scaling 300% when I try to get my resolution with the code I have shown I obtain 3840/3= 1280 x 2160/3 = 720. For a resolution of 1920 x 1080 with a scaling of 150%, I am getting again 1280 x 720 instead of 1920 x 1080. @BakkarBakkar

Comment: The win32 api/con simply takes the size of the "screen" whose area equates to yours under your chosen scaling. If you want to adjust for a given scaling, just multiply the api/con result by the appropriate factor (3 in this case).

Answer (score 2):

```py
import ctypes

scaleFactor = ctypes.windll.shcore.GetScaleFactorForDevice(0) / 100

print(scaleFactor)
```

if you get 3, your scale will be 300%

Answer (score 0):

To get the actual resolution as if your scaling is set to 100% you'll have to use this method:

```py
import win32con, win32gui, win32print
def get_dpi():
  hDC = win32gui.GetDC(0)
  HORZRES = win32print.GetDeviceCaps(hDC, win32con.DESKTOPHORZRES)
  VERTRES = win32print.GetDeviceCaps(hDC, win32con.DESKTOPVERTRES)
  return HORZRES,VERTRES
```

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: I came across the actual value here: [device pixel ratio](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtGui/QScreen.html#PySide2.QtGui.PySide2.QtGui.QScreen.devicePixelRatio)

If your scale is 150% your pixel ratio will be `1.5`.

```
from PySide6 import QtGui

screen = QtGui.QGuiApplication.primaryScreen()
scaled_pixel_ratio = screen.devicePixelRatio()
```