# How to get the height of Windows Taskbar using Python/PyQT/Win32

Tags: python, windows, winapi, pyqt

I am trying to make my GUI program align to the bottom-right of the screen on Windows. When the taskbar is not hidden, my program will just stand on top of the taskbar!

When using Python/PyQT/Win32, how can I:

1. Check if the taskbar's autohide function is on
2. Get the height of the taskbar

Comment: Related: [How do I get monitor resolution in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3129322/3357935)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to call [GetMonitorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144901.aspx) for the monitor of interest.  You then need to read the work area out of [MONITORINFO.rcWork](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145065.aspx).  This will exclude any part of the monitor reserved for taskbar and indeed any other reserved areas.

I don't believe you need to worry yourself about autohide because GetMonitorInfo should account for that.  In other words when autohide is enabled the work area will equal the monitor area.

Comment: Thank you very much! But I find that the usage of pywin32 is a little different from MSDN; Here is my code:screeninfo = win32api.GetMonitorInfo(1)

Comment: @good man obviously you need to map across between raw Win32 and pywin32 but the principles and underlying API calls are surely the same

Answer (score 23):

As [David Heffernan mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4358236/3357935), you can use [`GetMonitorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144901.aspx) with [`pywin32`](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/) to retrieve the monitor size. In particular, the work area will exclude the size of the taskbar.

**To get the work area size (desktop minus taskbar):**

```
from win32api import GetMonitorInfo, MonitorFromPoint

monitor_info = GetMonitorInfo(MonitorFromPoint((0,0)))
work_area = monitor_info.get("Work")
print("The work area size is {}x{}.".format(work_area[2], work_area[3]))
```

> The work area size is 1366x728.

**To get the taskbar height:**

```
from win32api import GetMonitorInfo, MonitorFromPoint

monitor_info = GetMonitorInfo(MonitorFromPoint((0,0)))
monitor_area = monitor_info.get("Monitor")
work_area = monitor_info.get("Work")
print("The taskbar height is {}.".format(monitor_area[3]-work_area[3]))
```

> The taskbar height is 40.

#### Explanation

First, we need to create a handle referencing the primary monitor. The primary monitor [always has its upper left corner at 0,0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/08/09/4300545.aspx), so we can use:

```
primary_monitor = MonitorFromPoint((0,0))
```

We retrieve information about the monitor with `GetMonitorInfo()`.

```
monitor_info = GetMonitorInfo(primary_monitor)
# {'Monitor': (0, 0, 1366, 768), 'Work': (0, 0, 1366, 728), 'Flags': 1, 'Device': '\\\\.\\DISPLAY1'}
```

The monitor information is returned as a `dict`. The first two entries represent the monitor size and the work area size as tuples (x position, y position, height, width).

```
work_area = monitor_info.get("Work")
# (0, 0, 1366, 728)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `QDesktopWidget` to retrieve information about the system's screens and subtract the working area from the total screen area.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
dw = app.desktop()  # dw = QDesktopWidget() also works if app is created
taskbar_height = dw.screenGeometry().height() - dw.availableGeometry().height()
```

In the case that the taskbar is on the sides of the screen however, this would return zero which is not particularly helpful. To resolve this issue, find the difference between `screenGeometry()` and `availableGeometry()` to find the size of the taskbar (and any other reserved spaces).

When the taskbar is set to autohide, the available geometry is unaware of the taskbar's size.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it with the builtin ctypes library

```
from ctypes import windll, wintypes, byref

SPI_GETWORKAREA = 0x0030
    
# This var will receive the result to SystemParametersInfoW  
desktopWorkingArea = wintypes.RECT()

_ = windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_GETWORKAREA,0,byref(desktopWorkingArea),0)

left = desktopWorkingArea.left
top = desktopWorkingArea.top
right = desktopWorkingArea.right
bottom = desktopWorkingArea.bottom
```

and getting your full screen values with taskbar can be as simple as

```
x,y = windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(0), windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)
```

which for me gives

```
print(left,top,right,bottom)
print(x,y)

0 0 5120 1400
5120 1440
```

so my taskbar is on the Y axis, 40px.