# Tkinter: Find the height of the taskbar (Windows 8)

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to position a window on the bottom right hand corner of the screen just above the taskbar. Is there a way to find the height of the taskbar to position the window just above the taskbar?

Comment: Try looking here, I think it might help. GetMonitorInfo seems to be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357258/how-to-get-the-height-of-windows-taskbar-using-python-pyqt-win32