# Is there a "WorkingArea" (as in C#) equivalent in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Windows users, generally, place the **task bar** at the bottom of the screen but occasionally place it to the left (vertical) and rarely at the top. I think, the `.WorkingArea` in C# takes care of this detail when asking for the usable dimensions of the screen. When using `tkinter`, I tempted to get the usable dimensions via `.winfo_screenwidth` & `.winfo_screenheight()` but those methods failed to take the location of the task bar into account.

Is there a way to detect the usable / visible dimensions of the screen in tkinter (or detect the location of the Windows task bar)?

Comment: Did you check the answers of [How to get the height of Windows Taskbar using Python/PyQT/Win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357258/how-to-get-the-height-of-windows-taskbar-using-python-pyqt-win32)?

Comment: @ssd, there will be no `C#` in answers, because it is completely `python` question. Meanwhile `C#` users that will get to this question be tag will be frustrated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the height of Windows Taskbar using Python/PyQT/Win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357258/how-to-get-the-height-of-windows-taskbar-using-python-pyqt-win32)