# python-wnck how to get monitor properties

Tags: python, wnck

`python-wnck` has Screen object which combines the areas of multiple monitors and gives it in `get_screen_size()`. How to get the size of individual monitors. I  am trying to move a window from one monitor to another

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of methods listed here : [How do I get monitor resolution in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129322/how-do-i-get-monitor-resolution-in-python)

I'm not sure if all the methods works for multiple screens. If you're using Window, try to run this code : http://code.activestate.com/recipes/460509-get-the-actual-and-usable-sizes-of-all-the-monitor/