# Getting the active root window using gtk.gdk in Python

Tags: python, gtk, screen, gdk

In Python, how would I get the active root window (or screen if you will) using gtk.gdk? I'm looking for a cross-platform solution.

The below code returns all my three monitors

```
gtk.gdk.get_default_root_window()
```

By active root window, I'd be happy with either the one the cursor is currently on, or the one the focused window is on.

**Potentially helpful links:**

[1] [python pygtk how to put a window on a specific display monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22772968/python-pygtk-how-to-put-a-window-on-a-specific-display-monitor)

**EDIT:** I attempted to implement the solution described in link #1, however `screen.get_active_window()` returns `None` and not an instance of `gtk.gdk.Window`.

Answer (score 3):

This should get you the active window:

```
from gi.repository import Gdk
active_window = Gdk.get_default_root_window().get_screen().get_active_window()
```

or if you are using pygtk

```
from gtk import gdk
active_window = gdk.get_default_root_window().get_screen().get_active_window()
```

The `active_window` is a [Gdk.Window](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gdk-3.0/classes/Window.html#Gdk.Window) ([gtk.gdk.Window](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gdkwindow.html) for pygtk).

Comment: Like I said in my main post `get_active_window()` return `None`. I suspect that it's because I'm on Windows as it seems to work on my Lubuntu laptop. I need a cross-platform solution.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot help you with  a solution that also works on Windows. You should also consider to mention in your question that you are looking for a cross-platform solution.

Comment: Edited my question to include cross-platform.

Comment: @Locercus it's a bit late, but I have a feeling there is no root window per monitor on Windows, just [one big root window (called the "desktop window")](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633504%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I'm not 100% sure though. You can poke around the [multi-monitor API documentation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145071%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you'd like. A Windows API expert will need to confirm all this for me...