# tkinter - full screen window on second display

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I coded a simple tkinter GUI for my 3D printer. It is a fullscreen display app that cycles through images.

- For each new layer, the app updates the img= parameter for a label widget
- In between layers it displays a black image as a safety precaution.

Currently, the GUI runs on top of a command-line interface. As a result, I can't see the progress of the build (e.g. current layer/total layers, build time elapsed, estimated build time completion).

I'd like the app to start on the **secondary monitor** in **fullscreen mode**.

- So far I've found that even if the correct XY position for the secondary monitor is specified, the --fullscreen attribute will default to the main screen. I have not been able to identify a programmatic workaround.
- I can manually hack it by using the control panel to switch the secondary and primary monitors, opening the app in fullscreen, then switching the primary monitors back. But this is painful, especially in a debug scenario where the app is potentially restarted many times.

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a window fullscreen in a secondary display with tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286660/how-to-make-a-window-fullscreen-in-a-secondary-display-with-tkinter)