# How to detect multiple screens

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.8

So you know when you connect a computer to a monitor and click extend display you get two displays and if you have another one you would have 3 different display screens...
So how do I create a tkinter program that detects multiple display screens and how do I create a program that add a second page to the other monitor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could probably try screeninfo module, and get information for each monitor

```
import screeninfo
print(screeninfo.get_monitors())
```

more explanation [here](https://github.com/rr-/screeninfo), you could explore yourself from there.
[here also a similar problem based on your case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286660/how-to-make-a-window-fullscreen-in-a-secondary-display-with-tkinter)