# Place opencv window in corners

Tags: python, opencv

Is there any portable way to use standard opencv for placing windows in corners of the screen? I can hardcode in values, but is there a way to get this behaviour portable?

All I can reliably do is top right...

```
import cv2
topLeft = cv2.namedWindow('')
cv2.moveWindow(topLeft, 0,0)
```

Comment: Perhaps you're interested in first obtaining the [screen resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129322/how-do-i-get-monitor-resolution-in-python)?