# Python win32api on Windows10 reports incorrect screen coordinates

Tags: python-2.7, winapi

I have just updated my system to Windows10.

I test my script, `win32api.GetSystemMetrics(0)` to get the screen width, which works perfectly fine on Windows7. However, on Windows10 it gives me an incorrect number.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you running a multimonitor configuration?  Is your monitor HiDPI and if so, is your program marked as HiDPI-aware?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/32541666/103167

Comment: It's a 1080p single display on a laptop.

Comment: Thank you @BenVoigt After I set `SetProcessDPIAware()`, the problem is solved. However, I think this question is related but not duplicate because mine is about getting screen resolution but the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32541475/win32api-is-not-giving-the-correct-coordinates-with-getcursorpos-in-python/32541666#32541666) is about getting pointer coordinate. I tried to search existing questions but could not find the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32541475/win32api-is-not-giving-the-correct-coordinates-with-getcursorpos-in-python/32541666#32541666).

Comment: No its exactly the same issue and really the same question. Everything about the screen coordinates is virtualize.