# How to make python ide work on high dpi displays without blurring

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter, ide

today I have encountered a strange problem where python ide would not scale the font correctly on my 1920*1080 screen. So i fixed it. Kinda

I knew that there was an option in windows where one could toggle the "Override high DPI scaling behavior". Problem is that this tab is only available for application e.g ".exe". Windows is a strange beast.

By default python ide has font size 9-10. That font on high res display just gets scaled by win 10

My solution is to manually enable DPI Awareness and then set the correct font size in class called run.py

As this is not a real question i will post the code and mark it as answered

It may not be compatible with displays that have higher resolution then 1920*1080, but hey it works :D

Comment: Take a look [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44422362/1070480)—it worked for me on Windows 10!

Answer (score 0):

I used ctypes to manually toggle "DpiAwareness" and then adjusted the font to my preference. And don't forget to "from ctypes import windll"

```
def fix_scaling(root):
"""Scale fonts on HiDPI displays.(Windows 10 only)"""
import tkinter.font
scaling = float(root.tk.call('tk', 'scaling'))
windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)
if scaling < 15:
    for name in tkinter.font.names(root):
        font = tkinter.font.Font(root=root, name=name, exists=True)
        size = int(font['size'])
        if size > 0:
            font['size'] = round(1.50*size)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Pycharm Community Edition.  In Distraction Free Mode, it feels a lot like idle but with readable menus on a 4k monitor.  It also has a python console, so it really seems to do everything one can do in idle.