# OpenCV imshow window too large - blurred image

Tags: python, windows, opencv

In OpenCV-Python when I create a `namedWindow` using `cv2.resizeWindow` with the dimensions of the image that I want to display, the window doesn't get resized properly.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

window_title = 'image'

img = cv2.imread('test.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
height, width = img.shape[:-1]

cv2.namedWindow(window_title, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow(window_title, width, height)
cv2.imshow(window_title, img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[See the attached screenshot to see the results.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fi8gl.png)

`test.jpg` is part of a screenshot of the VS Code window, 800x600 pixels.
The image window clearly is too large after the resize.

How can I easily resize the window to the correct size such that the displayed image doesn't get blurred?

I'm using Python 3.7.2, OpenCV 3.4.2, Windows 10 64-bit.

Comment: please post your code in your post, not in an image.

Comment: Just making some quick measurements in image editor, it seems it's shown as 1000x750.... i.e. both width and height are 25% larger. Hmm... do you happen to have UI scaling set to 125% in your OS? (Given how huge the original text looks, I guess this is a tiny FullHD screen, so it seems quite likely)

Comment: @DanMašek Man I feel so stupid that I didn't check the dimensions. Of course it's Windows's High DPI settings that interferes with OpenCV! I remember setting the UI scaling to 125% ages ago. Will write a thorough answer with workaround and solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DanMašek correctly noticed the 125% scaling of the OpenCV window compared to the original image size, which lead me to the solution.

This behavior is a result of the UI Scaling feature of more recent versions of Windows.
(Have a look under "Settings\System\Display\Scaling")

Since OpenCV doesn't mark its GUI windows as "DPI Aware", Windows scales them to whichever percentage the user has specified.

(Another side effect is that [win32gui.GetWindowRect()](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32gui__GetWindowRect_meth.html) returns seemingly incorrect coordinates as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/api/shellscalingapi/ne-shellscalingapi-process_dpi_awareness))

---

**Workaround**

Go to `python.exe`'s path, right-click the executable, choose 'Properties' and under the tab 'Compatibility' hit 'Change high DPI settings'. Then activate 'Override high DPI scaling behavior', set 'Scaling performed by' to 'Application'.

This will change the behavior for all sessions that this `python.exe` serves, though.
One could use virtual environments to overcome this limitation.

---

**Solution**

[This SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44398075/can-dpi-scaling-be-enabled-disabled-programmatically-on-a-per-session-basis) describes how one can set the scaling behavior on a per-session level within the Python code.