# Disable Windows OS scaling in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, windows-10

I'm working on a project where I created a window with tkinter. But when I run the application on a computer which has windows scaling turned to 150% the application becomes too big and unusable. Is there a way to change this, or disable windows scaling just for this application?

Comment: I am using Windows 10.

Comment: I had a simlar problem once and it was because I used multiple displays and my lower resolution display was set as my main display. However I ran the program on the higher resolution display and it messed up the scaling of the text.

Comment: How did you solve the problem?

Comment: I doubt that there's any way via `tkinter`, however there might some OS-specific way using `ctypes` if you can find the right Windows API function(s) to call. You might also be able to make it less of a problem by using a different `tkinter` layout manager (other than whichever one you're using now).

Comment: @CodeGuy if you have the same problem, then set the display you run the program on as your main display.

Comment: I just found this interest post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44398075/can-dpi-scaling-be-enabled-disabled-programmatically-on-a-per-session-basis

Comment: This question is just too vague. It's quite easy to write responsive tkinter GUIs that can easily scale and shrink. The fact that you're struggling with this could be simply because you have UI design that could be tweaked. Without seeing more about why your specific program is too large, it's going to be hard to give good advice.