# Tkinter GUI looks differently when run as an .exe (created by pyinstaller)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

After generating an .exe file using PyInstaller, the GUI displays differently. Buttons, images, and other elements appear with varying sizes. I used the .place method, specifying precise x and y coordinates, to display widgets into the GUI.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaeHz.png)

I attempted to address this issue by utilizing ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1) to adjust the DPI awareness level. However, this approach did not yield the desired solution.

Interestingly, I managed to resolve the problem through an alternative method. By right-clicking on the .exe file, accessing its Properties, navigating to the Compatibility tab, and choosing "Change high DPI settings," I was able to enable the "Override high DPI scaling behavior" option. Subsequently, clicking "OK" produced the desired GUI appearance. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6MqN.png)

My question is whether it's possible to directly solve this problem through code, rather than by property adjustments.

Comment: The best way to get a responsive UI is to use `pack` or `grid`, not `place`, though I realize that's not the question you're asking.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you include all lines of code of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44398075/can-dpi-scaling-be-enabled-disabled-programmatically-on-a-per-session-basis), or only the `ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)`?