# Number of pixels of screen python

Tags: python-2.7, screen, pixel

How can I calculate the number of pixels in screen (width, height) with python?

I want it to be adaptable to any screen, is this possible?

Comment: What do you do in case there are multiple screens?

Comment: Hi, now I don't need to implement it for multiple screens. Only with one screen. I want to know the number of pixels in one screen using python, is it possible?

Comment: which operating system?

Comment: I want to do it in Raspbian with a Raspberry Pi

Comment: I think Raspbian has some linux commands, like try this [`xrandr`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3129369/1248974) command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrowing from this question: [How do I get monitor resolution in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129322/how-do-i-get-monitor-resolution-in-python), there are several options. Here's one with Tkinter:

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

print screen_width * screen_height # (e.g.) 3686400 = 2560*1440
```

That [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129322/how-do-i-get-monitor-resolution-in-python) has a lot of different ways to do it, including getting information about multi-monitor setup, Windows OS implementations, DPI, etc.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it and I let you know!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with only two lines of code:

```
import pyautogui
print(pyautogui.size())
```

PyAutoGUI is a pretty useful module for programmatically controlling the mouse and keyboard.

Check out the website for it [here](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)