# Getting screen pixels taking into account the scale factor

Tags: python, pywin32

I'm trying to get my screen size using python. I keep getting the incorrect value because my code is taking into account the scale factor. For example: My screen resolution is set to: 2736 x 1824. My scale factor is 200% so when I execute my code I get 1368 x 912.

```
import win32api
width = GetSystemMetrics(0)
height = GetSystemMetrics(1)
print('Width:', width)
print('Height:', height)
```

Is there any way I can get the resolution as shown in my windows settings without the scale factor? I want to be able to read 2736 x 1824.

Comment: Can you get the scale factor? If so, why not just use it to work out the actual resolution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of, useful or related [Number of pixels of screen python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41834451/number-of-pixels-of-screen-python)

Answer (score 4):

```
import ctypes

scaleFactor = ctypes.windll.shcore.GetScaleFactorForDevice(0) / 100
```

You can get the scale factor via shcore using ctypes.
Then from this you can calculate the real resolution.

ie: scaleFactor 1.25 is 125%

Answer (score 1):

Your application is not [DPI aware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows). Windows has to lie to the application about the dimensions and magnify the GUI to fit the scale.

A quick fix:

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.SetProcessDPIAware()
```

For an executable it is recommended to set DPI awareness in the manifest file.

Comment: Do you know how to set it in the manifest file created by pyinstaller? Or is it an post-creation thing anyway? Thanks in advance.