# Is there a way to use ImageGrab on a specific window? (PIL)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pynput

This code is suppused to take a screenshot of a specific window using ImageGrab(PIL), however the screenshot is not acurrate and I have no Idea why.

here is a screenshot the code took(both not the right size and not in the right position)
[image: The screenshot]

and this is the code

```
import pygetwindow as gw
import PIL.ImageGrab
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
mouse = Controller()
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
keyboard = Controller()
chosenWindow = gw.getWindowsWithTitle('Discord')[0]
print(chosenWindow.topleft)
print(chosenWindow.bottomright)
Im = PIL.ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(chosenWindow.topleft[0],chosenWindow.topleft[1],chosenWindow.bottomright[0],chosenWindow.bottomright[1]))
Im.show()
```

Comment: Just to understand if the problem comes from `PIL` or `pygrabwindow`, does the size of the image matches the size that you would predict from the coordinates of the window you print?

Comment: The size doesn't match

Comment: Could you please add the coordinates you print, and the actual size of the image?

Comment: actual size: 1175x628
print size: 937x494
this is not 100% accurate but its close

Comment: I'm almost sure the problem comes from the PIL

Comment: Comparing the size, it is off by a factor of 1.25, suggesting you have display scaling set to 125% in Windows settings. The bounding box / coordinates you are passing to PIL are unscaled. The issue is that `pygrabwindow` appears to be ignoring the 125% display scaling.

Comment: This answer solved my problem: [Your application is not DPI aware.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53893352/23567183)
Then you may want to [adjust the offsets manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63012359/23567183)