# python setting console fullscreen(or maximum window size) using win32api

Tags: python, winapi, cmd

so I'm trying to resize the console window to the maximum size on startup.

I tried using the win32api as follows:

```
import win32api

console_handle = win32api.GetStdHandle(win32api.STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
win32api.SetConsoleDisplayMode(console_handle, CONSOLE_FULLSCREEN_MODE)
```

But it says that win32api doesn't have a SetConsoleDisplayMode function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a windows command to change the size of the console:

```
import os
os.system("mode con cols=50 lines=20")
```

cols is the width, lines is the height

Comment: thank you! Helped a lot. But another thing is how can I position the console so it doesn't stick out, because this way the console is as large as I need but right and bottom sides are sticking out of the screen, any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I modified the code from this link to achieve it:
[How do I get monitor resolution in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129322/how-do-i-get-monitor-resolution-in-python)

This is my code below which looks at the maximum size of the screen and fills the screen if its bigger than a predetermine size (1366 x 768).  The screen resolution size 1366 x 768 is the smallest I can display my program.

```
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics

print("Width =", GetSystemMetrics(0))
print("Height =", GetSystemMetrics(1))

if GetSystemMetrics(0) >= 1366 and GetSystemMetrics(1) >= 768:
    Window.size = (GetSystemMetrics(0), GetSystemMetrics(1))
    Window.fullscreen = True
else: 
    Window.size = (1366, 768)
```

This worked on a 'windows' system for me.  You'll have to test for other systems.

Answer (score 0):

Use win32console instead of win32api:

```
import win32console
h = win32console.GetStdHandle(win32console.STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
h.SetConsoleDisplayMode(win32console.CONSOLE_FULLSCREEN_MODE, win32console.PyCOORDType(0,0))
```

Comment: it says the handle is invalid :/

Comment: I know I noticed it and changed, still the same error