# Dynamically resize images in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library, tkinter-canvas

I have several images that I need to display in a Tkinter window (I'll probably use a canvas to display them - possibly a label). These images will take up about a third of the screen. I need the image-screen ratio to be consistent when the user uses different sized monitors.

So say the user uses a tiny monitor, the images need to take up the same photo-screen ration on the small screen, to when the user uses a massive 4K monitor.

Will Tkinter automatically do this for me? Or will I have to implement it myself - if so, is that even possible?

I don't have any code because I have no idea where to start. I thought that I could use PIL or pillow maybe, but I'm fairly new to them.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You need to get current screen resolution: [How do I get monitor resolution in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129322/how-do-i-get-monitor-resolution-in-python)

2) Then you need to adjust size of your image ([How do I resize an image using PIL and maintain its aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273946/how-do-i-resize-an-image-using-pil-and-maintain-its-aspect-ratio)) and/or your window (https://yagisanatode.com/2018/02/23/how-do-i-change-the-size-and-position-of-the-main-window-in-tkinter-and-python-3/)

So the code should look like that:

```
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics
from Tkinter import Tk

screen_width, screen_height = GetSystemMetrics(0), GetSystemMetrics(1)

root = Tk() # this is your window
root.geometry("{}x{}".format(screen_width//2, screen_height//2)) # set size of you window here is example for 1/2 screen height and width

img = Image.open("picture_name.png", "r") # replace with picture path
width, height = screen_width//4, screen_height//4 # determine widght and height basing on screen_width, screen_height
img.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS) 

# todo: create more Tkinter objects and pack them into root

root.mainloop()
```

This should probably solve your problem. Regarding Tkinter usage, there are a lot of tutorials, example: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/

Comment: Awesome! One question though - will this change the size of the original image in the directory, or create a copy of the original image and resize that? Or will it not change anything and resize the image every time the program is run and not change any of the image files?

Comment: Method 'resize' does not influence real image file. So in fact, it only updates Image object data. Of course you can save it into the file (the same or different) but it is up to you how you use that.