# How to make the PyGame window open in full-screen mode

Tags: python, pygame, screen-size

I'm working with `pygame` to make an alien shooter game. I want to make the game window adapt to the user's screen size so that it automatically starts in full-screen mode, by detecting their screen size. I'm thinking of using `pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))`, but I don't know how to make Python detect the user's screen size. How do I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129322/how-do-i-get-monitor-resolution-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get monitor resolution in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129322/how-do-i-get-monitor-resolution-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with that code:

```
pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
```

It will start your game in full screen mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pygame.display.Info()`

The docs say:

current_h, current_w: Height and width of the current video mode, or of the desktop mode if called before the display.set_mode is called.
(current_h, current_w are available since SDL 1.2.10, and pygame 1.8.0) They are -1 on error, or if an old SDL is being used.1.8.0)

`pygame.display.Info()` creates an Info Object with the attributes `current_h` and `current_w`. Create the Info Object before you call `display.set_mode` and then call `display.set_mode` with `current_h` and `current_w` from the object.

Example:

```
infoObject = pygame.display.Info()
pygame.display.set_mode((infoObject.current_w, infoObject.current_h))
```