# Resolution of a maximized window in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, ctypes, resolution

Is there a **built-in function** or **straight-forward** way to get the **resolution** of a **maximized window** in **Python** (e.g. on Windows full screen without the task bar)?
I have tried several things from other posts, which present some major **drawbacks**:

1. ctypes

```
import ctypes 
user32 = ctypes.windll.user32 
screensize = user32.GetSystemMetrics(0), user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)
```

Simple, but I get the resolution of the full screen.

2. tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()  # Create an instance of the class.
root.state('zoomed')  # Maximized the window.
root.update_idletasks()  # Update the display.
screensize = [root.winfo_width(), root.winfo_height()]
root.mainloop()
```

Works, but it isn't really straight-forward and above all, I don't know how to exit the loop with root.destroy() or root.quit() successfully. Closing the window manually is of course not an option.

3. matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(1)
plt.switch_backend('QT5Agg')
figManager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
figManager.window.showMaximized()
print(plt.gcf().get_size_inches())
```

`[6.4 4.8]` is then printed, but if I click on the created window, and execute `print(plt.gcf().get_size_inches())` again, I get `[19.2  10.69]` printed, which I find higly inconsistent! (As you can imagine, having to interact to get that final value is definitely not an option.)

Comment: u want the size of the window only?

Comment: Yes, in number of pixels.

Comment: have u tried `win32gui` or `pyGetWindow`

Comment: with pyGetWindow all you have to do is `win = pygetwindow.getWindowsWithTitle('name_of_window')[0]` and then `print(win.size)`. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: For option 2, you don't need to call `root.mainloop()`.

Comment: @acw1668: wow, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Cool Cloud: thanks for your input. The problem with your method is that it assumes that I already have a maximized window.

Comment: mmmmm okay i see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [[MS.Docs]: GetSystemMetrics function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsystemmetrics) (***emphasis*** is mine):

> **SM_CXFULLSCREEN**
>
> 16
>
> ***The width of the client area for a full-screen window*** on the primary display monitor, in pixels. To get the coordinates of the portion of the screen that is not obscured by the system taskbar or by application desktop toolbars, call the [SystemParametersInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa) function with the SPI_GETWORKAREA value.

Same thing for *SM_C**Y**FULLSCREEN*.

Example:

> ```py
> >>> import ctypes as ct
> >>>
> >>>
> >>> SM_CXSCREEN = 0
> >>> SM_CYSCREEN = 1
> >>> SM_CXFULLSCREEN = 16
> >>> SM_CYFULLSCREEN = 17
> >>>
> >>> user32 = ct.windll.user32
> >>> GetSystemMetrics = user32.GetSystemMetrics
> >>>
> >>> # @TODO: Never forget about the 2 lines below !!!
> >>> GetSystemMetrics.argtypes = [ct.c_int]
> >>> GetSystemMetrics.restype = ct.c_int
> >>>
> >>> GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)  # Entire (primary) screen
> (1920, 1080)
> >>> GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXFULLSCREEN), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYFULLSCREEN)  # Full screen window
> (1920, 1017)
> ```

Regarding the ***@TODO*** in the code: check [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58610333/c-function-called-from-python-via-ctypes-returns-incorrect-value/58611011#58611011).

Comment: Fantastic, thanks a lot! I still need some time to get used to that syntax/logic but it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the window to persist simply remove the mainloop method from the tkinter code.

```py
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()  # Create an instance of the class.
root.state('zoomed')  # Maximized the window.
root.update_idletasks()  # Update the display.
screensize = [root.winfo_width(), root.winfo_height()]
```

I also found this that might be helpful and more what you are looking for; I am using Linux, so I am unable to test it.

```py
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics

print("Width =", GetSystemMetrics(0))
print("Height =", GetSystemMetrics(1))
```

[How do I get monitor resolution in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129322/how-do-i-get-monitor-resolution-in-python)

Comment: thank you so much for your answer!
- 1st method works very well (as @acw1668 pointed out in the main thread comments). I am sorry for that basic concept that I ignored.
- 2nd method: unfortunately I get the same output as by using `ctypes.windll.user32`, i.e. the resolution of the full screen, task bar inclusive (e.g. in my case (1920, 1200) instead of (1920, 1137)).