# Screenshot on multiple monitor setup pyautogui

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, windows, macos

I am using **pyautogui** in python for the screenshots

```
import pyautogui
screen = pyautogui.screenshot()
screen.save("file.jpg")
```

It works fine on a single screen on all platforms. But in a multiscreen system, it combines the two screens in a single screenshot. but I want a screenshot of a monitor which one is currently on use.

Comment: There is an optional `region` parameter. Together with [some screen info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129322/how-do-i-get-monitor-resolution-in-python), you should be able to achieve what you want. Be aware that position can be negative for some screens.

Answer (score 8):

### `mss` package can easily solve this problem

#### 1. Install the package

`pip install mss`

#### 2. Take screenshots

**First Monitor**

```py
import os
import os.path

import mss


def on_exists(fname):
    # type: (str) -> None
    """
    Callback example when we try to overwrite an existing screenshot.
    """

    if os.path.isfile(fname):
        newfile = fname + ".old"
        print("{} -> {}".format(fname, newfile))
        os.rename(fname, newfile)


with mss.mss() as sct:
    filename = sct.shot(output="mon-{mon}.png", callback=on_exists)
    print(filename)
```

**Second Monitor**

```py
import mss
import mss.tools


with mss.mss() as sct:
    # Get information of monitor 2
    monitor_number = 2
    mon = sct.monitors[monitor_number]

    # The screen part to capture
    monitor = {
        "top": mon["top"],
        "left": mon["left"],
        "width": mon["width"],
        "height": mon["height"],
        "mon": monitor_number,
    }
    output = "sct-mon{mon}_{top}x{left}_{width}x{height}.png".format(**monitor)

    # Grab the data
    sct_img = sct.grab(monitor)

    # Save to the picture file
    mss.tools.to_png(sct_img.rgb, sct_img.size, output=output)
    print(output)
```

**Use with OpenCV**

```py
import mss
import cv2
import numpy as np

with mss.mss() as sct:
    
    # Get information of monitor 2
    monitor_number = 2
    mon = sct.monitors[monitor_number]

    # The screen part to capture
    monitor = {
        "top": mon["top"],
        "left": mon["left"],
        "width": mon["width"],
        "height": mon["height"],
        "mon": monitor_number,
    }
    output = "sct-mon{mon}_{top}x{left}_{width}x{height}.png".format(**monitor)

    # Grab the data
    sct_img = sct.grab(monitor)
    img = np.array(sct.grab(monitor)) # BGR Image
    
    # Display the picture
    cv2.imshow("OpenCV", img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

### 3. Important Notes

- `sct.monitors` will contain more than one item even if you have a single monitor because the first item will be the combined screens

```py
>>> sct.monitors # if we have a single monitor
[{'left': 0, 'top': 0, 'width': 1366, 'height': 768}, 
{'left': 0, 'top': 0, 'width': 1366, 'height': 768}]
```

```py
>>> sct.monitors # if we have two monitors
[{'left': 0, 'top': 0, 'width': 3286, 'height': 1080}, 
{'left': 1920, 'top': 0, 'width': 1366, 'height': 768}, 
{'left': 0, 'top': 0, 'width': 1920, 'height': 1080}]
```

Comment: Your important note is gold. I was so confused why there were two list entries when I only had one monitor connected. +1, my man.

Answer (score 5):

found an solution [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/99fer7/pyautogui_with_multiple_monitors/e4neq6p?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)!

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
from functools import partial
ImageGrab.grab = partial(ImageGrab.grab, all_screens=True)
```

pyautogui.screenshot() will capture all screens.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4):

If you visit the official documentation website of you will see this :

> Q: Does PyAutoGUI work on multi-monitor setups.
>
> A: No, right now PyAutoGUI only handles the primary monitor.

You can use the mss module for this purpose.

```py
from mss import mss
#One screenshot per monitor:

for filename in screenshotter.save():
    print(filename)

#Screenshot of the monitor 1:

for filename in screenshotter.save(screen=1):
    print(filename)

#Screenshot of the monitor 1, with callback:

def on_exists(fname):
    ''' Callback example when we try to overwrite an existing
        screenshot.
    '''
    from os import rename
    from os.path import isfile
    if isfile(fname):
        newfile = fname + '.old'
        print('{0} -> {1}'.format(fname, newfile))
        rename(fname, newfile)
    return True

for filename in screenshotter.save(screen=1, callback=on_exists):
    print(filename)

#A screenshot to grab them all:

for filename in screenshotter.save(output='fullscreen-shot.png', screen=-1):
    print(filename)
```