# How could I get monitor resolution in right way with Python？

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I use an another question’s comment function， It has been worked but also makes my Thinker GUI scaling

```
import ctypes
user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
user32.SetProcessDPIAware()
[w, h] = [user32.GetSystemMetrics(0), user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)]
```

my question is how to make my GUI recover to normal DPI before I used this function
user32.SetProcessDPIAware()

Comment: This question is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129322/how-do-i-get-monitor-resolution-in-python)

Comment: Normally if you do `user32.SetProcessDPIAware()` you put a value in the interface and that value will lead to different behavior. See, [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellscalingapi/ne-shellscalingapi-process_dpi_awareness#constants) and the [function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellscalingapi/nf-shellscalingapi-setprocessdpiawareness) you are using, However, tkinter offers you a built in way to get the screen_width and screen_height. Its not clear to me what you have trouble with and why do you think you need these function in a tkinter app.

Comment: @Thingamabobs Yes indeed,Thinter offers funtions like  
`screenWidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screenHeight = root.winfo_screenheight()`
, However if Windows set scaling it return the error results ,and its trun right when I use user32.SetProcessDPIAware() ,but also effect resolution of  my GUI forever

Comment: @diwen have you tried all the values 0,1,2. It sounds like 2 ist the value you are searching for.

Comment: [before use user32.SetProcessDPIAware()][1]


[use user32.SetProcessDPIAware()][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuHu8.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IROQU.jpg

Thank you for your reply, Looking at these screenshots, I just want to get my monitor resolution，but not my GUI.
I tried everything I could, I have tried all the values 0,1,2 they affect to my program are same @Thingamabobs

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that includes a tkinter window with that behaviour.

Comment: It works very well when I restart VS Code and rebuild the project, whatever how I  set the scaling.I guess `user32.SetProcessDPIAware()` doesn't sense system changes correctly when compiled, Thanks a lot dude~
https://github.com/Weeeendi/Picture2Text/tree/develope 
This is my repository for this project if you are interested in this project @Thingamabobs