# Getting Display resolution with python isn't accurate

Tags: python, tkinter, ctypes, pywin32, screen-resolution

In Settings > Display it says that my screen resolution is set to 1920x1080 [image]. But I've tried to get it with 3 different methods in python:

**1- With Tkinter:**

```py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
Width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
Height= root.winfo_screenheight()
```

**2- With win32api:**

```py
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics
Width = GetSystemMetrics(0)
Height = GetSystemMetrics(1)
```

**3- With ctypes:**

```py
import ctypes
Width = ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(0)
Height = ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)
```

All of these methods keep returning Width = 1536 and Height = 864 and not the resolution that it says in my display settings.

***How could I get the same resolution as displayed in the Display Settings (1920x1080)?***

Comment: @MauriceMeyer: Which answer in the link are you thinking answers this question?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer If you're talking about the accepted answer then no it doesn't.

Comment: The one using `SetProcessDPIAware()`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129322/how-do-i-get-monitor-resolution-in-python/26539115#26539115

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is caused by the scaling setting that is set to 125%.

So I found 2 solutions:

**The First one [answered by @spacether in @rectangletangle's question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26539115/14698534):**

```py
import ctypes
user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
user32.SetProcessDPIAware()
Width = user32.GetSystemMetrics(0)
Height = user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)
```

**The Second one:**

```py
import win32con, win32gui, win32print
def get_dpi():
  hDC = win32gui.GetDC(0)
  HORZRES = win32print.GetDeviceCaps(hDC, win32con.DESKTOPHORZRES)
  VERTRES = win32print.GetDeviceCaps(hDC, win32con.DESKTOPVERTRES)
  return HORZRES,VERTRES
```

Comment: 2nd link is broken.

Comment: @Shmack It seems that the page isn’t available anymore, but I still got the code that we need in my answer, so no need for the rest of the website

Comment: Okay, that's fine. I didn't know if you wanted to hunt down the website that you were referencing or not. Just wanted to let you know.