# Python display image on second monitor

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'm using the following script to display an image and it's working. I would like to send the output (image) to a secondary display which connected through HDMI. What's the best way to implement this?

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("path_to_file/1.png")
im.show()
```

I found the solution below (`screeninfo` package) to get monitor info, etc. Not sure how it can be used to send the output to a different screen.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31171430/5510713

Answer (score 0):

Set display device in terminal before running your code.
Follow these steps

This command at a console would provide the available video devices in linux os

```
ls /dev/video*
```

This allow to use video device, as here I used 0.

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```