# CustomTkinter Automatic window size detection

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I apologize in advance if this issue has already been mentioned, but I am using customtkinter and I have created an application on my laptop (1920x1080, Scaling 100%). The application I am working on will be used on other displays and I dont't know their resolution or scaling. I would like my app to change on the basis of the display resolution and scaling. Is that possible and if yes does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance,

Cheers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get monitor resolution in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129322/how-do-i-get-monitor-resolution-in-python) (btw I assume your mean monitor size detection)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Tranbi, to achieve a "responsive" app you will want to check out the display resolution to resize your app accordingly.

You should probably also plan for users to resize the app themselves and for the app to subsequently change appearance. To achieve this you can simply get the window size with print `CTk`'s `winfo_geometry()` method.

```py
root.winfo_geometry() # => tuple(int: x, int: y)
root.winfo_width() # => int: x
root.winfo_height() # => int: y
```