# Difference between MFC and windows API in getting screen resolution

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, screen-resolution

I set the windows screen resolution to *1920x1080*.
I have c++ windows API program and need to use `GetSystemMetrics` function.

```
int x = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);//retun x=1536
int y = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);//retun y=864
```

As you see I get the different value from 1920x1080.
 But If I use `MFC` headers (**afx.h**) and use **MFC dlls** in the program settings, then the return value x,y are equal to windows screen resolution (1920x1080).

Why the two methods are not same?

How can I get the correct windows screen resolution in my programs without using MFC?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any chance you are running on Windows with the 125% scaling? Since 1,25 * 1536 = 1920 and 1,25 * 864 = 1080? The I assume MFC is not DPI aware.

Also, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630392/getsystemmetrics-returns-wrong-value-for-sm-cxscreen) on how to mark your application as DPI aware.